# In HTTP/1.1 are connections shared across multiple chrome tabs to the same origin?

Tags: google-chrome, http, http2, http-1.1

In HTTP/2, one connection is used per origin.

In HTTP/1.1 are connections shared across multiple chrome tabs to the same origin?

Comment: Why do you have the assumption that http/2 uses one connection that is shared across multiple chrome tabs if they have the same origin?

Comment: I checked in chrome://net-internals live HTTP2_SESSION by opening two tabs for same website which is on http2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In Chrome, HTTP/1.1 sockets are stored in a pool when they are not active. A request from any tab may end up using any socket in the pool.

That having been said...  Incognito tabs use their own independent socket pool (All incognito tabs for a profile share just one socket pool, though).  Isolated apps use their own socket pools.  Different profiles and guest mode use their own socket pools.  Global requests not tied to a profile use their own socket pool.  And there are a couple other socket pools hanging around (Cloud print uses its own, as does safe browsing).

Each socket pool also separates "uncredentialed sockets" from those that use some form of identity (cookies, HTTP auth, etc).

Source: [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/S3TEvmRWcNE)